# Are there any precautionary measures I can take for a beginner?

Tags: undo-redo

When first starting out using vim, I was nervous that I'd get lost in some foreign mode that could potentially wreak havoc. I felt like there was never really any "safety net" preventing me from a major blunder, possibly leading to a catastrophe with either my system or the file I was working on.

I've built up my own personal confidence, but surely there might be other beginners who feel the same way I did when starting out. Are there safeguards that can be put in place for someone learning the ropes? Any type of sandboxing, restrictions, or safety features would be ideal.

Comment: In my opinion, this is both too broad (asking for just a big list) and primarily opinion based (there's no way to tell whether an answer is objectively "correct").

Comment: As a beginner, `u` is my best friend.. Is there a reason you feel it's not enough of a safety net?

Comment: backup. backup. backup... I once did a halfdrunk fumble-finger in `mutt` and deleted my entire INBOX (never figured out what I did exactly). These sort of errors can occur in any keyboard-based program...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker (off-topic) `D` `.` `<enter>` would do it...

Answer (score 4):

- Become comfortable with vimtutor. Doesn't matter if you mess the file up, because it's a temporary version.
- Learn to undo something with normal mode and `u`.
- It's kinda difficult to have a catastrophe with your system, by accident from Vim. If you find yourself accidentally typing `:! rm / -rf` then you've got bigger problems than Vim. Don't do that at all. **Anywhere**.
- Remember that if you run `:q` without saving, it won't write the file. So if you open something up and it gets ruined, don't do a `:w` an `:x` or a `:wq`. Quit straight out and try again.

Comment: I agree with vimtutor. I learned from there. It's the best tutorial.
As for the 4th bullet do not forget `:x` along with `:wq`.

Comment: I think a cation "**do not do that, will destroy your computer**" should be added to any instance of that curse you wrote there. ;)